# MySQL - complicated request

Tags: mysql

I have a DB that has 2 tables:

1. projects

- id
- user_id
- type (0 - private, 1 - shared)

2. friends

- user1_id
- user2_id
- friendship (0 - not friends, 1 - friends)

lets say our user_id is A.

How do I do a query that will select * from projects where either (1) user_id is A or (2) projects.type=1 and user_id is what user2_id is in friends if both user1_id in friends is A and status is 1) or (3) projects.type=1 and user_id is what user1_id is in friends if both user2_id in friends is A and status is 1)

Got a bit confused...

Tried this, but didn't work

```sql
    SELECT * FROM projects 
        WHERE 
        (user_id = (SELECT 
                    CASE 
                    WHEN user1_id=A THEN user2_id
                    WHEN user2_id=A THEN user1_id
                    END
                    FROM friends
                    WHERE friendship=1)
         AND type=1)
```

Comment: **Show us what you’ve done so far** so that we have something to start with. It’s much easier for us to help you with existing code, and people are far more likely to help when they don’t have to start from zero with "How do I do this?"

Comment: Make sure you use parentheses properly when mixing AND with OR. You can group ANDs and you can group ORs, but don't mix them.

Comment: @AndyLester Have updated

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure in proper form (`CREATE TABLE...`), sample data and the expected output corresponding to that sample data

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it should've been just IN instead of =

```sql
SELECT * FROM projects 
        WHERE 
        (user_id IN (SELECT 
                    CASE 
                    WHEN user1_id=A THEN user2_id
                    WHEN user2_id=A THEN user1_id
                    END
                    FROM friends
                    WHERE friendship=1)
         AND type=1)
```